# SwiftUI view get views in the body or define view as property

Tags: swiftui, view, binding

I am trying to get the view inside the `body` for observing purpose, but looking for different ways the view inside the `body` can be accessed.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var userNameText: String

    var body: some View {
        startObservingInput()
        return TextField("hello", text: $userNameText)
    }

    func startObservingInput() {
       // How do we get TextField instance here.
      // Option 1 - Pass as parmeter here.
        // Option 2 - Is there a way to get view from body ex: self.body.textFieldView
        // Option 3 - can create as a property in CotentView but the text binding refers to self which will not be allowed before its initalized so that will fail to compile
        //var textField  = TextField("hello", text: $userNameText)
    }
}
```

1. Option 1 is simple, where we pass the `TextField` view.
2. Option 2 is something I am looking for, if we can get any view inside the hierarchy. In this case Text Field.
3. Option 3, Tried to create a property but I get the following error.
   ex:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var userNameText: String
    
    var textField  = TextField("hello", text: $userNameText)
......
}
```

```
Cannot use instance member '$userNameText' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

Comment: Views are immutable values, there is no point in observing them because they never change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI is different from what you're probably used to. Unlike `UIKit`, you don't "store" views in properties. There's no delegates either.

Instead, you directly pass in a property — `userNameText` — that will be linked to the text field's text. Since this updates itself automatically, you can use the [`onChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) modifier to observe changes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userNameText: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("hello", text: $userNameText)
            .onChange(of: userNameText) { newValue in
                print("Text changed to: \(newValue)")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, look at it:

```
    //
//  ViewProp.swift
//  SwiftDemo1
//
//  Created by CreoleMacbookPro on 12/19/22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ViewProp: View {
    @State var userNameText: String = " "
 
    var body: some View {

        let textField: TextField<Text>  = TextField("hello", text: $userNameText)
        let simpleText: Text = Text("Hello, World!")
        
       let _ = print(type(of: textField))
        startObservingInput(textField: textField)
        Button {
            userNameText = "Jatin Bhuva"
        } label: {
            Text("Press Me..")
        }

//        textField
    }
    
    func startObservingInput(textField: TextField<Text>)  -> some View {
        textField
       // How do we get TextField instance here.
      // Option 1 - Pass as parmeter here.
        // Option 2 - Is there a way to get view from body ex: self.body.textFieldView
        // Option 3 - can create as a property in CotentView but the text binding refers to self which will not be allowed before its initalized so that will fail to compile
        //var textField  = TextField("hello", text: $userNameText)
    }
}

struct ViewProp_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewProp()
    }
}
```